# Problem while using Load when clause?

Tags: sql, database, plsql, oracle10g, sql-loader

I need to reject the rows from an external table which starts (first column of every row) with some special characters (eg. `~` `\` etc) in a CSV file.

For that I have used `LOAD WHEN` clause in the `ACCESS PARAMETERS` clause. I have been using the following statement in the Access parameters clause:

```
load when (1:1) != '~'
```

But it throws an error stating "INVALID CHARACTER"

If I try to use the below statement,

```
load when (empname != '~empname')
```

It throws:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEFETCH callout
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.EMP_PROCEDURE", line 101
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Line 101 in the procedure is `select * from emp;`

How do I use `LOAD WHEN` clause - any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

```
LOAD WHEN (1:1) != 0x'7e'
```

Reference: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16536/et_params.htm#i1009513

Comment: Thanks for the advice, it is working. Since I am using TOAD I tried with single quotation, but when i tried with LOAD WHEN (1:1) != 0x''7e'' it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the ASCII value of a tilde?

```
load when (1:1) != CHR(126)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but Iam facing the same issue                                                   ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-00554: error encountered while parsing access parameters

KUP-01005: syntax error: found "(": expecting one of: "and, badfile,
byteordermark, characterset, column, data, delimited, discardfile,
disable_directory_link_check, exit, fields, fixed, load, logfile, language,
not, nodiscardfile, nobadfile, nologfile, date_cache, or, processing, readsize,
string, skip,"

Comment: CONTD.,                                                                         KUP-01007: at line 2 column 40
ORA-06512: at "SYS.ORACLE_LOADER", line 19
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.EMP_PROCEDURE", line 101
ORA-06512: at line 1